# Objective C " * " syntax and usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, particle-filter

I am re-writing the particle filter library of iOS in Swift from Objective C which is available on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/codeswell/ibeacon-localization) and I have a question regarding a syntax of Objective C which I cannot understand.

The code goes as follows:

```
- (void)setRssi:(NSInteger)rssi {
_rssi = rssi;

// Ignore zeros in average, StdDev -- we clear the value before setting it to
// prevent old values from hanging around if there's no reading
if (rssi == 0) {
    self.meters = 0;
    return;
}    
self.meters = [self metersFromRssi:rssi];

NSInteger* pidx = self.rssiBuffer;
*(pidx+self.bufferIndex++) = rssi;

if (self.bufferIndex >= RSSIBUFFERSIZE) {
    self.bufferIndex %= RSSIBUFFERSIZE;
    self.bufferFull = YES;
}    
if (self.bufferFull) {

    // Only calculate trailing mean and Std Dev when we have enough data
    double accumulator = 0;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < RSSIBUFFERSIZE; i++) {
        accumulator += *(pidx+i);
    }
    self.meanRssi = accumulator / RSSIBUFFERSIZE;
    self.meanMeters = [self metersFromRssi:self.meanRssi];

    accumulator = 0;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < RSSIBUFFERSIZE; i++) {
        NSInteger difference = *(pidx+i) - self.meanRssi;
        accumulator += difference*difference;
    }
    self.stdDeviationRssi = sqrt( accumulator / RSSIBUFFERSIZE);
    self.meanMetersVariance = ABS(
                                  [self metersFromRssi:self.meanRssi]
                                  - [self metersFromRssi:self.meanRssi+self.stdDeviationRssi]
                                  );
}    
  }
```

The class continues with more code and functions which are not important and what I do not understand are these two  lines

```
NSInteger* pidx = self.rssiBuffer;
*(pidx+self.bufferIndex++) = rssi;
```

Variable pidx is initialized to the size of a buffer which was previously defined and then in the next line the size of that buffer and buffer plus one is equal to the RSSI variable which is passed as a parameter in the function.

I assume that * has something to do with reference but I just can't figure out the purpose of this line. Variable pidx is used only in this function for calculating trailing mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Get your old C and C++ books out. * is used for declaring pointers, dereferencing pointers, and multiplication. Just as in C and C++.

Comment: This is fundamental C stuff, and you *must* know the basics of C before you attempt to learn Objective-C.  Otherwise you will develop all sorts of misconceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let explain those code:

1. `NSInteger* pidx = self.rssiBuffer;` means that you are getting pointer of the first value of the buffer.
2. `*(pidx+self.bufferIndex++) = rssi;` means that you are setting the value of the buffer at index `0+self.bufferIndex` to `rssi`and then increase `bufferIndex` by `1`. Thanks to @Jakub Vano point it out.

In C++, it will look like that

```
int self.rssiBuffer[1000]; // I assume we have buffer like that
self.rssiBuffer[self.bufferIndex++] = rssi
```

Comment: In C++ it will look absolutely the same way as in Obj-C. Maybe replace "in C++" with "With array syntax..."

Comment: Yes, in C++ we can also have the same way as in Obj-C, but I think the way in my answer is easier to understand. And of course, it is an example for the questioner because he doesn't understand the way in Objc

Comment: ".. setting the value of the buffer at index `0+self.bufferIndex+1`" -  this is not correct, actual index is `0+self.bufferIndex`. `pixd + self.bufferIndex++` means that incrementation of `self.bufferIndex` happens only after the pointer has been incremented.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I will correct the answer.